# Why is typecasting (as Class) in FDT formatter formated with the relational whitespace option?

Tags: actionscript, fdt

Turning of the whitespace around relationals formats the code into:

```
getDefinitionByName("Helloworld") as Class
```

into

```
getDefinitionByName("Helloworld")asClass
```

Has this been changed in FDT 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tired it in FDT 4.5.x and it works fine.

What version of FDT are you using?  In FDT 4.0 - a new formatter was introduced, with many bug fixes and improvements.

Comment: I am using 3.5. Thanks for answering